# Extending classes when more than one of the same name

Tags: php, oop

I have the following two files:

```
/var/www/stuff/controller.php
/var/www/otherStuff/controller.php (PS, it extends the above file)
```

When executing file `/var/www/stuff/tryThis.php` with the following script, which controller will be invoked?

```
require_once('/var/www/otherStuff/controller.php');
$controller=new controller();
```

What about when executing file `/var/www/stuff/tryThat.php` with the following script, which controller will be invoked?

```
$controller=new controller();
```

Is there anything I should do to make it more explicit?

Thanks

Comment: You couldn't have two classes named `controller` anyways. If the `otherStuff` file includes/requires  `controller` and both try to define a `controller` class, then which one one tries to do it SECOND will fail.

Comment: @MarcB.  Exactly!, and why I am asking the question.  I have `if($useThis) {require_once('newFile.php');$controler=new controller();} else  {$controler=new controller();}`.  Both should never be available at the same time.

Comment: well, if the otherstuff file has `<?php include(stuff/controller.php); class controller extends controller {...}`, it's not going to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments below your entry, you cannot declare a class with the same name twice in the global namespace.

However, you could do this with namespaces and even have an autoloader that works off of those namespaces.  Or you could change the name of one of the classes.

[Namespace Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)
[Namespace Tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/)

---

#### Basic Namespace Example

For `stuff/controller.php`

```
namespace stuff 

class Controller {
  ...
}
```

For `otherStuff/controller.php`

```
namespace otherStuff

class Controller extends \stuff\Controller {
   ...
}
```